# A library is not working on Nougat (API Level 24)

Tags: android

I used `compile 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:rotatingtext:1.0.2'` in `Android` app. It is working in `Android` `Marshmallow` `API 22` and lower versions. To be more precise, It rotates text with `Animation`. In `Android` with `Api level 22` and lover it is showing text with `Animation`. But higher versions don`t support. What should I do to be supported in all versions of Android devices.  Please Help.
Here is Source Code:
**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.abdusoli.rotatingtext;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.animation.BounceInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.sdsmdg.harjot.rotatingtext.RotatingTextWrapper;
import com.sdsmdg.harjot.rotatingtext.models.Rotatable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf");
        Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Reckoner_Bold.ttf");

        RotatingTextWrapper rotatingTextWrapper = (RotatingTextWrapper) findViewById(R.id.custom_switcher);
        rotatingTextWrapper.setSize(35);
        rotatingTextWrapper.setTypeface(typeface2);

        Rotatable rotatable = new Rotatable(Color.parseColor("#FFA036"), 2000, " ", "Word01", "Word02");
        rotatable.setSize(35);
        rotatable.setAnimationDuration(600);
        rotatable.setTypeface(typeface);
        rotatable.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

        rotatingTextWrapper.setContent("This is ?", rotatable);

    }

}
```

**gradle.build(Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abdusoli.rotatingtext"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.+'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:rotatingtext:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: What problem do you see?

Comment: https://github.com/sdsmdg/RotatingText/issues/14 and https://github.com/sdsmdg/RotatingText/issues/5

Comment: No problem. But It is not showing anything. But it is supposed to show animation text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the library does not support higher versions

[Issue has been raised on the repo in github](https://github.com/sdsmdg/RotatingText/issues/14)

Comment: can you copy solution to your answer from link. Imagine link stops working tomorrow :)

Comment: A fix is being being worked on, using Rx-Java.
I am busy and will update the library when I get time

Comment: Sure This library currently cannot support API 24 and higher versions. Thanks for Help.